# Join query confusion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My confusion revolves around the following:

```
SELECT t3.id, t3.name SUM(t1.quantity_available) as 'quantity' FROM product_merchant as t1
INNER  join product_category as  t2
(inner join category as t3
on t2.category_id=t3.id  on t1.product_id = t2.product_id )
where t1.merchant_id= 3  GROUP BY t3.id
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(t1.quantity_available) as 'quantity' FROM product_merchant as t1 INNER join' at line 1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(t1.quantity_available) as 'quantity' FROM product_merchant as t1
INNER join' at line 1

Comment: gettinh this issue

Comment: You're missing a `,`. What is your question?